# Can I run startActivity() method in Dispathers.IO?

Tags: android

I created 2 Coroutine with Dispathers.IO
I know that Dispathers.IO run code in background, and it can't run startActivity()

but.. it works and I don't know the reason. please explain me.
(Sorry for bad english)

```kotlin
    private fun tryLogin() = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ApiClient.disableToken()
        val isSuccessful = TokenHelper.tryLoginWithAccessToken()
        if(isSuccessful) {
            loadMember()
        } else {

            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, LoginOrSkipActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }
    }


    private fun loadMember() = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val result = MemberDataHelper.readMember()
        if(result.isSuccessful) {
            PreferenceManager.saveToPreferences(Constants.KEY_MEMBER_DATA, result.data as MemberData)
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        } else {
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, LoginOrSkipActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }
    }
```

but.. it works and I don't know the reason. please explain me.
(Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dispatchers.IO` is a coroutine dispatcher that is optimized for offloading blocking IO tasks to a shared pool of threads.

While it is generally not recommended to perform UI operations such as `startActivity()` on a background thread, it may still work in some cases.

However, this behavior is not guaranteed and can lead to unexpected issues and crashes. It is always recommended to perform UI operations on the main thread.

You can use `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` to switch to the main thread within a coroutine before calling `startActivity()`.

Here’s an example of how you can modify your `tryLogin()` function to perform the `startActivity()` call on the main thread:

```
private fun tryLogin() = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    ApiClient.disableToken()
    val isSuccessful = TokenHelper.tryLoginWithAccessToken()
    if (isSuccessful) {
        loadMember()
    } else {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, LoginOrSkipActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, you can modify your `loadMember()` function to perform the `startActivity()` calls on the main thread.